# In Python how do you put a program inside a program

Tags: python

I would like to take all my simple math programs for basic financial ratios and compile it into one program where I could print the list of the programs and allow the user to select the one in which he or she is wishing to run. How would this be accomplished?

What I have tried so far has ended up in just running through all of the programs and then allowing to state the one you wish to do after you have gone through all the previous ones ex: opening the file and running it, going through each one the having to put margin() to run the program margin().

Thank you for your help in advance. I am new to programing and all my experience is self taught through readings and videos and I wish to do this in python the language I am most familiar with.

Comment: What's wrong with the Operating System?  It has directories.  Python has packages.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: I am confused by your question. Nothing is wrong with the o/s

Comment: Can you not just import all the files, and then choose what functions to fun based on user input?

Comment: I don't get it. What do you have? A number of programs in .py files? What do you want?

Comment: I have been in this position before, just not with python. The user has no idea what is going on, he can probably only compile some simple programs. He has no idea of the overall picture, so he barely knows what to ask. I know, because I have been there.

Comment: F oak is correct and i have a number of simple programs in .py and would like to get them into one or just write a whole new one that can run a guess several small ones by a selection inputs to run a small program inside the larger one.

Comment: And amccormack I can do that and have but would like to know if there is a way i could just put them into one to save user hassle in the long run

Comment: do you have multiple functions in your files? or are you just writing one __main__ for every file and creating a new file every time you want to write a new function.  What I mean is are your programs anything more than just a function or two?

Comment: the majority are just one or two functions per file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are looking for, but please comment if I'm not understanding you correctly.

One of the easiest ways to accomplish what you are looking for is to just use the python prompt itself.  If you put all your programs in one file (making sure that there are no overlapping names) then what you could call those functions from one program, call it masterprogram.py
In your prompt then, import masterprogram to get started

Running a `dir(masterprogram)` will list all the functions of your masterprogram, and running `help(masterprogram.somefunction)` will print the documentation for that function.

If you would like an example of how this would work, try opening up your python prompt and running observe the following:

```
>>> import math
>>> dir(math)
['__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan',
 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'erf', 'er
fc', 'exp', 'expm1', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'gam
ma', 'hypot', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'ldexp', 'lgamma', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 'mod
f', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'trunc']
>>> help(math.ceil)
Help on built-in function ceil in module math:

ceil(...)
    ceil(x)

    Return the ceiling of x as a float.
    This is the smallest integral value >= x.

>>>
```

Comment: That will do the job ill have to give it a try after class but it looks like it shold work thank you for your help.

Comment: For reference, the way you document python functions is through docstrings: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/